# How to improve the performance of an R function that returns coordinates for aligned sequences?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a datatable of aligned coordinates. For example, the sequence from "start_A" to "end_A" aligns to the sequence from "start_B" to "end_B" on "chromosome_B":

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

pos1 <- sort(sample(1:1000, 40))
start_A <- pos1[(1:20)*2 - 1]
end_A <- pos1[(1:20)*2]
start_B <- sample(1:1000, 20)
end_B <- start_B + (end_A - start_A)
alignment <- data.table(start_A = start_A,
                    end_A = end_A,
                    chromosome_B = c(2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                    start_B = start_B,
                    end_B = end_B)
```

And a vector of coordinates. For example:

```
pos <- sample(unlist(seq2(alignment$start_A, alignment$end_A)), 15)
```

I have written a function that given both inputs, will return the coordinate and chromosome of each aligned coordinate. For example:

```
alakazam <- function(alignment, pos){

  colnames(alignment) <- 
c("start_A","end_A","chromosome_B","start_B","end_B")
  vec_list_A <- seq2(alignment$start_A, alignment$end_A)
  vec_list_B <- seq2(alignment$start_B, alignment$end_B)
  out_list <- list()

  for (i in 1:length(pos)){

    pos_A <- pos[i]
    pos_B <- rep(NA, length(vec_list_A))

    for (j in 1:length(vec_list_A)){
      tmp1 <- vec_list_A[[j]]
      tmp2 <- vec_list_B[[j]]
      if (length(tmp1[which(tmp1 %in% pos_A)]) != 0){
        pos_B[j] <- tmp2[which(tmp1 %in% pos_A)]
      }
      out <- data.table(pos_A = rep(pos_A, length(vec_list_A)),
                    chromosome_B = alignment$chromosome_B,
                    pos_B = pos_B)
      out <- out[complete.cases(out),]
      print(j)
    }
    out_list[[i]] <- out
    print(i)
  }
  output <- do.call("rbind", out_list)
  return(output)
}

output <- alakazam(alignment, pos)
```

The data I need to apply this to is, however, very large, and the function is too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to improve performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Rewriting your code in C++ using the Rcpp package will give a huge speed enhancement.

Comment: You're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minem seems close, but I think the original "start_A" coordinates should be kept to get the correct results.

```
posDT <- data.table(order1 = seq_along(pos),
                    pos1 = pos,
                    pos2 = pos,
                    key = 'pos1')
alignment[,start_A1 := start_A]
v1 <- alignment[posDT, on = .(start_A <= pos2, end_A >= pos2)][,-c("start_A", "end_A")]
v1[, pos_B := pos1-start_A1 + start_B]
setorder(v1, order1)
out <- v1[, .(pos_A = pos1, chromosome_B, pos_B)]
out
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are asking the same questions over and over ([How to count matches between a vector and dataframe of sequence coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294563/how-to-count-matches-between-a-vector-and-dataframe-of-sequence-coordinates/56295410#56295410))

here you have made a mistake

```
  out <- data.table(pos_A = rep(pos_A, length(vec_list_A)),
                chromosome_B = alignment$chromosome_B,
                pos_B = pos_B)
  out <- out[complete.cases(out),]
```

is one level too deep in loop.
It should probably be like:

```
for (i in 1:length(pos)){

  pos_A <- pos[i]
  pos_B <- rep(NA, length(vec_list_A))

  for (j in 1:length(vec_list_A)){
    tmp1 <- vec_list_A[[j]]
    tmp2 <- vec_list_B[[j]]
    if (length(tmp1[which(tmp1 %in% pos_A)]) != 0){
      pos_B[j] <- tmp2[which(tmp1 %in% pos_A)]
    }
  }
  out <- data.table(pos_A = rep(pos_A, length(vec_list_A)),
                  chromosome_B = alignment$chromosome_B,
                  pos_B = pos_B)
  out <- out[complete.cases(out),]
  out_list[[i]] <- out
  print(i)
}
```

this should be faster, but i am not sure if this gives the result that you want.

using data.table merge:

```
  posDT <- data.table(order1 = seq_along(pos),
                     pos1 = pos,
                     pos2 = pos,
                     key = 'pos1')
  v1 <- alignment[posDT, on = .(start_A <= pos2, end_A >= pos2)]
  v1[, pos_B := start_B + (start_A - pos1)]
  setorder(v1, order1)
  out <- v1[, .(pos_A = pos1, chromosome_B, pos_B)]
  out
```

Results are a little bit different:

```
    pos_A chromosome_B pos_B
 1:   433            1   343
 2:   975            2   810
 3:   749            4   375
 4:   936            2   435
 5:    81            2   404
 6:   621            2   684
 7:    58            2   404
 8:   297            4   506
 9:   551            3   121
10:   719            2   537
11:   202            4   532
12:   492            3   582
13:   712            2   537
14:   910            1    39
15:   909            1    39
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matching_pos <- function(alignment, pos){

  colnames(alignment) <- c("start_A", "end_A", "chromosome_B", "start_B", "end_B")
  # convert pos to dt
  posDT <- data.table(pos1 = pos, pos2 = pos, key = 'pos1')
  # merge dt
  v1 <- alignment[posDT, on = .(start_A <= pos2, end_A >= pos2)]
  v1 <- v1[,c("chromosome_B", "start_B", "end_B", "pos1")]
  v1 <- alignment[v1, on = c("chromosome_B", "start_B", "end_B")]

  # subset by direction
  v1_plus <- v1[end_B >= start_B]
  v1_minus <- v1[start_B > end_B]

  # calculate difference and subtract
  v1_plus$diff <- v1_plus$pos1 - v1_plus$start_A
  v1_plus$pos2 <- v1_plus$start_B + v1_plus$diff
  v1_minus$diff <- v1_minus$pos1 - v1_minus$start_A
  v1_minus$pos2 <- v1_minus$start_B - v1_minus$diff

  v1 <- rbind(v1_plus, v1_minus)
  out <- v1[,c("start_A","end_A", "pos1", "start_B","end_B", "pos2", "chromosome_B")]
  colnames(out) <- c("start_A","end_A", "pos_A", "start_B","end_B", "pos_B", "chromosome_B")
  # out <- v1[,c("pos1", "pos2", "chromosome_B")]
  # colnames(out) <- c("pos_A", "pos_B", "chromosome_B")
  out <- out[order(pos_A)]

  return(out)
}
```